# Python module ecdsa errors while running paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, ecdsa

I am trying to install paramiko module..it fails with the below error

```
python ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 30, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/tmp/build-paramiko/paramiko-1.12.0/paramiko/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/tmp/build-paramiko/paramiko-1.12.0/paramiko/transport.py", line 45, in <module>
    from paramiko.ecdsakey import ECDSAKey
  File "/tmp/build-paramiko/paramiko-1.12.0/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ecdsa import SigningKey, VerifyingKey, der, curves
ImportError: No module named ecdsa
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed with the paramiko installation ?

Comment: How are you trying to install it? You shouldn't need to manually install dependencies.

Comment: I am installing using "python setup.py install" after downloading the package.... I have already installed ecdsa using the same steps

Comment: You really don't need to do this. Install Pip and just run `pip install paramiko`.

Comment: i understand that pip is the package manager for paramiko..but i would like to have ht ecdsa as a package separately so that i install it everytime i build my application.

Comment: Pip is the Python package manager. It has nothing to do with the `paramiko` module.

Comment: great..pip works with ease..thanks for the suggestion and patience in answering :)

Answer (score 2):

Download the package from 'https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa' and install it using command

```
python setup.py install
```

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use easy_install to install the lost module "ecdsa" ,which like: easy_install ecdsa,
but you have to ready easy_install first!

Comment: please expand a bit on what should be done to avoid the error!

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
    from ecdsa import SigningKey, VerifyingKey, der, curves
ImportError: No module named ecdsa
```

suggests that the python-ecdsa package is missing, you can install it with

```
pip install ecdsa
```

Though in general, you shouldn't need to install paramiko from sources. You can install it with

```
pip install paramiko
```

that has the benefit of automatically resolving the dependencies of a package